# Выбор алгоритма хеширования для получения хеш-значения файла

Tags: php, файлы, хеширование

В данный момент использую `sha1_file()` для получения хеш-значения файла.
Но, уже давно имеется функция `hash_file()`, для которой можно задать алгоритм.

Какой алгоритм использовать для получения хеш-значения файла?
* `sha1_file()` был выбран исходя из статистических данных, где говорилось что `sha1_file()` более популярен, чем `md5()`.

Comment: По каким критериям выбирать предлагаете? По популярности? По длине хэша? В общем, куча факторов требует учета.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, скорость, коллизии. Вот только не знаю актуально ли последнее для файлов. А длина чем больше, тем меньше коллизий или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абсолютно любой, какой вам нравится. Основные требования к хэш-функциям - это стойкость к подбору и вероятность коллизии (при распределении, близком к случайном, этот параметр обратно пропорционален длине возвращаемого значения), в вашем же случае оба параметра не принципиальны - вам не нужно получать уникальное значение, поэтому коллизии не имеют значения (до тех пор, пока вероятность случайно получить совпадение подписей поврежденного и нормального файлов достаточно мала), стойкость к подбору тоже не играет никакой роли, потому что вы не используете функцию для защиты каких-либо данных от взлома. Другими словами, для создания подписей к файлам будет достаточно практически любого алгоритма - в этой сфере нет больших требований к хэш-функции.

Comment: Etki, получается, что для файлов важным является только скорость обработки. Смею предположить, что более новые алгоритмы, такие как sha256 или sha512 сработают быстрее sha1? А что по поводу длины значения хранимого в БД, если я произвожу поиск файлов в БД по хешу, значит ли это: более длинный хеш, больше времени на поиск. Получается стоит выбирать между скоростью получения хеша и скоростью нахождения его в БД. Для скорости получения sha256, а для скорости нахождения в БД - sha1, верны ли мои предположения?

Comment: @Plush если вы производите поиск по хэшу, то появляется условие на вероятность коллизии (хотя даже она довольно мала и ею можно пренебречь). Разницу в скорости вы скорее всего не заметите, там накладные расходы будут больше, но sha-1 будет (ненамного) быстрее любого алгоритма из семейства sha-2 (-256, -512, etc.).

Comment: Возможно, вам известно какой алгоритм: md5 или sha1 более подвержен коллизии?

Comment: @Plush нет, но оба должны давать достаточно малую вероятность коллизии.